# Finding a single Unique value in a python list

Tags: python, numpy, unique

I am trying to create a function that returns a unique value on a python list.
So for example:

```
List = [1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,]
```

How would I go about returning the unique value, 2.

I have tried the following:

```
import numpy as np

def find_uniq(arr):
    abc = np.array(arr)
    return list(np.unique(abc))
```

**However when I try this ^^^ , it returns (2) two values , the 1 and the 2. Since they are both unique values to the list. Though I only want the 2.**

Comment: Are you trying to find the element which appears only once (assuming this is always the case)? You can try `count` method for each unique value and return the element with count equal to 1.

Comment: You could use a `Counter` object from the `collections` module

Comment: @Carlos, that is correct. This is what I will most likely be doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter( [1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,])
>>> c
Counter({1: 8, 2: 1})
>>> print ([k for k,v in c.items() if v==1])
[2]
```

This will tell you quickly if there is no unique element, or more than one.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in numList:
    if numList.count(i) == 1 :
        print ("unique", i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Return counts from `numpy.unique` and then select values that have count of 1:

```
lst = [1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1]
val, cnt = np.unique(lst, return_counts=True)
val[cnt == 1]
# [2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the unique elements using set, and return the element which appears only once:

```
for ele in set(arr):
    if arr.count(ele) == 1:
        print(ele)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def check_window(i,a):
    return all(a[i+d]!=a[i] for d in (-1,1))

l = [1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1]
ls = sorted(l)
ls.append(None)

uniques = [ls[i] for i in range(1,len(ls)-1) if check_window(i, ls)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**For every unique element append it to list**

```
def find_unique(nums_list):
    result = []
    for i in nums_list :
        if nums_list.count(i) == 1 :
            result.append(i)
    return result

print(find_unique([1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1]))
```

**If you want to find only first unique element**

```
def find_unique(nums_list):
    for i in nums_list :
        if nums_list.count(i) == 1 :
            return i
    
print(find_unique([1,9,1,1,2,1,1,1,1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Encountered on Codewars ('Find the unique number' by isqua)

The first solution I came up with below, has an issue where it takes too long to return what I need. It doesn't create additional arrays, but I guess iterating through a giant list would be a problem.

```
for n in arr:
        if arr.count(n) == 1:
            return n
        else: None
```

The method below worked perfectly, and leads me to believe that python sorts faster than iterating.

```
x,y = sorted(arr)[0], sorted(arr)[-1]
return x if arr.count(x) == 1 else y
```